# Python 2D Array - Referencing specific part of grid

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, pygame

I have a 10x10 grid currently filled with zeros and rendered to the screen using Pygame's freetype module.

How would I render the list contents in my for loop rather than hardcode a '0' string?

```
import pygame
import pygame.freetype

# Define some colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

# Create a 2 dimensional array. A two dimensional
# array is simply a list of lists.
grid = [[0 for x in range(10)] for y in range(10)]

# Initialize pygame
pygame.init()

# Set the HEIGHT and WIDTH of the screen
WINDOW_SIZE = [255, 255]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE)

# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:

    # Set the screen background
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    # Draw the grid
    for row in range(10):
        for column in range(10):
            pygame.freetype.Font(None, 32).render_to(screen, (column * 32, row * 32), '0', WHITE)

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `enumerate` here to get the coordinates of your grid with any size you want:

```
    for i, row in enumerate(grid):
        for j, item in enumerate(row):
            pygame.freetype.Font(None, 32).render_to(screen, (j * 32, i * 32), str(item), WHITE)
```

This way you don't need to know the size of the grid upfront. 
Then simply get the string representation of cell item with `str()`.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I think it would be better to create the font outside the loop, rather than re-creating it every iteration.